# How to make `overflow-x` to work instead of `overflow-y`?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent, it has multiple children, when the parent width overflows, i like to show horizontal scroll bar.

I don't want to use the 'display:inline-block' property, since they are producing white spaces between them.

here is my try:

```css
.parent{
  width:250px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  height:100px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.children{
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">children 1</div>
  <div class="children">children 2</div>
  <div class="children">children 3</div>
  <div class="children">children 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox

```css
.parent {
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.children {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">children 1</div>
  <div class="children">children 2</div>
  <div class="children">children 3</div>
  <div class="children">children 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `float` property & add `display:inline-block`

```
.children{
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  /*float:left;*/
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use table-cell

```css
.parent {
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.children {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
}
.children::before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">children 1</div>
  <div class="children">children 2</div>
  <div class="children">children 3</div>
  <div class="children">children 4</div>
</div>
```